# Lowercase all text except elements in a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this: `s = "I am Enrolled in a course, MPhil since 2014. I LOVE this SO MuCH."`

And a list of words `list = ["MPhil", "MuCH"]`

I am looking for a regex code that is able to lowercase all the text except the elements of the list.

I found this regex solution that is able to lowercase all except the words between `''`:

`s = re.sub(r"\b(?<!')(\w+)(?!')\b", lambda match: match.group(1).lower(), s)`

But I don't know how to turn it into my case.

I tried to split the text and check if it's from the list or not but I didn't found it really practical.

If someone could give me a hint or suggest me something I'll be thankful

Comment: *"I tried to split the text and check if it's from the list or not but i didn't found it really practical."* - Why not? That seems to be the most straight-forward solution to me.

Comment: Do you need to check for `'` at all?  Try `re.sub(fr"\b(?!(?:{'|'.join(word_list)})\b)\w+\b", lambda m: m.group().lower(), s)`

Comment: @Tomalak because i have a very long text, and also when i split i will get some words stuck with some dots and comma

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no the ' was just a sort of solutions am looking for, i want to lower all text except for some specific words in a list with regex

Comment: ...so? Commas and dot's don't change when you use `.upper()` or `.lower()`.

Comment: @Tomalak but if you split on whitespace `MuCH.` will not be found in your `list = ["MPhil", "MuCH"]` and will therefore be made `.lower()`.

Comment: @Tomalak no but when i split on spaces in a text like this : hello my name is? , i will get is? as an element not the word only

Comment: You can strip punctuation from the word before you check if it's in the list.

Comment: Sure you can but it gets to the point where `regex` is more practical.

Comment: @Ma0 yes thank you!

Comment: @Ma0 Sure, but what good is a regex solution that is so complex that the OP has problems following (they "found" the other regex, which means they don't really understand that one, either). Spit, strip, check if in list seems like a preferable, more manageable approach to me.

Comment: I see your point and I sincerely hope that the OP sees it too. That being said, I believe this is their decision to make.

Comment: @Ma0 Of course it is. Then again, not every problem needs a regex solution, and it's ok to say that in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see whether the word you've matched is in the set of words to keep as-is:

```
import re

words_to_keep = {"MPhil", "MuCH"}


def replace_if_not_in_keeplist(match):
    word = match.group()
    if word in words_to_keep:
        return word
    return word.lower()


s = "I am Enrolled in a course, MPhil since 2014. I LOVE this SO MuCH."
s2 = re.sub(r"\w+", replace_if_not_in_keeplist, s)

print(s)
print(s2)
```

outputs

```
I am Enrolled in a course, MPhil since 2014. I LOVE this SO MuCH.
i am enrolled in a course, MPhil since 2014. i love this so MuCH.
```